# Install library in ros

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am wondering how I would incorporate a library in ROS. The library I am trying to install is called ulapi to communicate with the kuka robot we have in the lab.

Thanks

Update (7.13.16):
Here is part of my code that I am trying to add the ulapi library. Might be useful.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>

//library for type of message sent to gazebo topics
#include <std_msgs/Float64.h>

//libraries to control model in gazebo
#include <geometry_msgs/Pose.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <gazebo_msgs/ModelState.h>
#include <gazebo_msgs/SetModelState.h>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <robsim_gazebo/ulapi.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    //initialize node
    ros::init(argc, argv, "publisher_node");

    //create node handle
    ros::NodeHandle rob_pose;

    ros::NodeHandle a1a2;
    ros::NodeHandle a2e1;
    ros::NodeHandle e1a3;
    ros::NodeHandle a3a4;
    ros::NodeHandle a4a5;
    ros::NodeHandle a5a6;
    ros::NodeHandle a6tp;
```

Here is the part of my CMakeLists.txt file

```
add_library(unix_ulapi src/unix_ulapi.c)
#target_link_libraries(publisher_node unix_ulapi)

add_library(ulapi_getopt src/ulapi_getopt.c)
#target_link_libraries(publisher_node ulapi_getopt)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239271/install-library-in-ros/) by [justinkgoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27238/justinkgoh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2016-07-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-07-12**:
Are you just asking how to *install* the library (`.so` file) in some specific location, or do you want to *integrate* the library into a ROS node? The fist is a file copy action, the second requires you program a node (a C++ program fi) and call into the libraries functions.

**Comment by [justinkgoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27238/justinkgoh/) on 2016-07-13**:
The files I have are C and H. I am use to installing libraries for Arduino and was wondering how to do it for ROS.

**Comment by [senreot](https://answers.ros.org/users/27465/senreot/) on 2016-07-13**:
After adding the libraries you need to link them to the executable.
Try to uncomment the target_link_libraries() lines or add the next line at the bottom of the CMakeList:

`target_link_libraries(publisher_node ulapi_getotp unix_ulapi)`

**Comment by [justinkgoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27238/justinkgoh/) on 2016-07-14**:
When I do that I get an error that says this:

```
CMake Error at robsim/robsim_gazebo/CMakeLists.txt:214 (target_link_libraries):
        Cannot specify link libraries for target "publisher_node" which is not
        built by this project.
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-07-14**:
off-topic, but what I find much more interesting: what are you doing with robsim, gazebo and ulapi? :)

**Comment by [senreot](https://answers.ros.org/users/27465/senreot/) on 2016-07-14**:
This is because the executable has another name.
Try replacing `publisher_node` with the name of the executable.

If you can show us the complete CMakeList we can help you  better ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you be more specific about "install" ?

Check the library with cmake then compile your code and link it

This is just a sample, modify regarding to your needs

```
find_package( PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules( ulapi REQUIRED ulapi )

add_executable( my_exec src/my_source.cpp )
target_link_libraries( my_exec ${ulapi_LIBRARIES} )
```

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2016-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [justinkgoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27238/justinkgoh/) on 2016-07-13**:
What I mean by install is that I want to use the .c and .h files from ulapi (which is what we use to talk to the robot arms we have in the lab) in my c++ code I have written. I am familiar with the way you install libraries for arduino if that is of any help.